# Decode content-encoding gzip using Spring WebClient

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I am calling a web service using Spring WebClient (Spring 5.1.3). The service responds with `content-type: application/json` and `content-encoding: gzip`

`ClientResponse.bodyToMono` then fails with the error "JSON decoding error: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31))" which I assume is because the content has not been decoded before trying to parse the JSON.

Here is code snippet (simplified) of how I create the WebClient

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));
return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();
```

I then use the WebClient to make the call:

```
webClient.get().uri(uri)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip")
    .exchange()
```

The HTTP request has 2 headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

The response has the following headers:

```
set-cookie: xxx
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 1175
content-encoding: gzip
cache-control: no-store, no-cache
```

By doing the following I am able to manually decode the GZIP content and get valid JSON from the result

```
webClient.get().uri(uri)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header("accept-encoding", "gzip")
        .exchange()
        .flatMap(encodedResponse -> encodedResponse.body((inputMessage, context) ->
                inputMessage.getBody().flatMap(dataBuffer -> {
                    ClientResponse.Builder decodedResponse = ClientResponse.from(encodedResponse);
                    try {
                        GZIPInputStream gz = new GZIPInputStream(dataBuffer.asInputStream());
                        decodedResponse.body(new String(gz.readAllBytes()));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    decodedResponse.headers(headers -> {
                        headers.remove("content-encoding");
                    });
                    return Mono.just(decodedResponse.build());
                }).flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(Map.class))
```

Comment: May you post the JSON?

Comment: gzip decoding is supported by default by the reactor netty client. Could you post code snippets showing how the webclient is being created? Could you show as well the HTTP request and response headers and bodies?

Comment: @BrianClozel I have added some code snippets. I have now been able to manually decode the content successfully, but it still does not seem to handle this automatically

Comment: `inputMessage.getBody()` returns a `Flux<DataBuffer>`, should it be aggregated to a `Mono<DataBuffer>` using `DataBufferUtils.join(inputMessage.getBody())`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This feature is supported natively by the reactor netty client.

You should create `HttpClient` like this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
             .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext))
             .compress(true);
```

And then there's no need to add the accept encoding request header since it's done for you.

Note that [this bit is done by the connector itself](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/bfb49c7249316604ca86e64070bc35f2575c5cb8/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/reactive/ReactorClientHttpConnector.java#L44) when you don't provide a custom `HttpClient` instance.

Comment: Thanks @Brian it now works after adding compress(true). Can I ask why this is necessary and why it could not have been detected by the content-encoding header and automatically decoded?

Comment: The reactor Netty client doesn’t set up the required decompression support by default. It requires an additional Netty handler in the chain that does the job.