# Failed to decode chunked response in webclient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, webclient, chunked-encoding

I was trying to call a backend using webclient, which is "chunked" response. But, it appears StringDecoder failed to decode chunked response. As I can see following line logged

```
LN="o.s.c.c.StringDecoder"   [3d736ae4]  Decoded "?�????????�V�RPPPrO-?J-.��+NU�R220P(.MNN-.N+�Q�?+).I,)-�?�%�??)(y$??T*?$�d(��?)���(䦖d�(q�r??���}X???"
```

However, actual response from backend is plain json with following response header :

```
Content-Encoding : gzip
Vary : Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
Transfer-Encoding : chunked
```

Couldn't find any similar post on SO, which could point to handle chunked type response using webclient.

Code snippet of webclient part :

```
Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> response = client.get().uri(url)
                .retrieve();
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, t -> Mono.empty())
                .toEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: This looks like the gzipped response didn't get decompressed. How are you creating the WebClient? Which version of Spring Framework/Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: The data is gzipped (`Content-Encoding : gzip`) but your code isn't doing anything to unzip. Also, please post the rest of the code, currently not enough to see what's going, or for others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @BrianClozel Thanks for response. Yeah correctly pointed, it was due to gzipped response, I found your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53958076/10471045, which helped. I initially thought, it was something to do with chunked response.