# How to decompress gzip response body using Spring RestClient?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest-client

The [oficial docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/rest-clients.html) don't mention how to configure RestClient to decompress a gzip response. By default it doesn't seem to decompress it like [WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53958076/1490806) does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by adding `io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:1.1.15` dependency and using `ReactorNettyClientRequestFactory` as a request factory:

```
RestClient.builder()
                .requestFactory(new ReactorNettyClientRequestFactory())
                .build()
                .get()
                .uri(uri)
                .retrieve()
                .body(String.class);
```

Then gzip decompression is done automatically.